# Laravel Nova: What could cause a custom field not to show on edit form?

Tags: laravel-nova

I want to create a custom field to add a customized tiptap editor. The files are being built etc, but somehow the field is not showing on the form. There's no errors or warnings which makes it hard to debug.

So the question is: what could cause this? Why would a field just not show? Where should I look?

Comment: Since you say there are no errors, perhaps you didnt clear the browser cache (CTRL+SHIFT+R in chrome).

Comment: Thanks, but I already managed to solve it. I hadn't realized that you could rebuild the nova files to enable Vue devtools. Once I could inspect the vue instance it showed me the errors and fixed them.

Comment: @GavinHewitt - You should post your comment as an answer and then accept it to prevent this showing up as an unanswered question.