# Custom field isn't showing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I created a custom field in Nova via `php artisan nova:field` and added it to my model but it's not getting rendered anywhere. I went through all the points mentioned in the documentation - https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/customization/fields.html, nothing helped.

Comment: have you register it

Comment: @flakerimi yes, it is registered in `FieldServiceProvider` as well as in `composer.json`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63663133/laravel-nova-what-could-cause-a-custom-field-not-to-show-on-edit-form#comment112603032_63663133

Comment: I tried from an incognito window, didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out eventually. The thing is I have run `npm run dev` several times which apparently didn't create `dist`. But `npm run prod` did the trick so I'm going to go with it.